# Creating slider or carousel for bundle product in magento?

Tags: magento-1.9, bundled-product

I want to create a bundle products for my estore but the bundle product has more than 50 products

So i want to add carousel or slider to these product. I tried adding some sliders but it is not working??

Please suggest me with some ideas.

Comment: try using flexlider, and loop on your bundle's child products, then feed the loop iterations to a specific (new) template of yours that will handle 1 item of the flexslider.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, if you want to use a slider, you will need to add your bundle items as checkboxes or radio buttons.  If you add them as selects or multiselects you won't be able to add a slider.

Now, depending on the type of bundle products (checkboxes or radio) you need to edit one of these files:

- `/app/design/frontend/{package}/{theme}/template/bundle/catalog/product/view/type/bundle/option/checkbox.phtml`
- `/app/design/frontend/{package}/{theme}/template/bundle/catalog/product/view/type/bundle/option/radio.phtml`

Pick a slider that looks nice (this is entirely up to you) and add it to those pages. Most of the sliders work out of the box with `<ul>` elements, so you are in luck because the templates that render the bundle items use `<ul>`s.
If something does not work, you should explain it in the question. We cannot guess what has gone wrong.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.. The external javascript file is not working i added the javascript file in header block of page.xml but still not working